# Bridge edge loops maintaining quad topology?

Tags: modeling, topology, loop

Blender's bridge edge loops feature does not produce quad topology in some situations it could. Say I want to bridge the selected edge loops:

[image: 1]

"Bridge edge loops" produces something like this (Loop tool's Bridge feature isn't much better):

[image: 2]

But I want this:

[image: 3]

Is there any way to get that result automatically?

This situation comes up in modeling eg. when transitioning from narrower area to wider, even though in the pictures both top and bottom parts are drawn equally wide.

Comment: By default with current blenders tools? No. Manually ... Extrude two middle edges, Bridge and Tris to Quads (with Max Shape Angle set to 90).

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is exactly what *vklidu* suggested *(just to close the question)*:

No, it can't be done automatically, but it can be done manually:

1. Extrude the two middle edges (<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Create a bridge between the top edge and the bottom edge with `Bridge Edge Loop`
3. Turn each two faces into a quad (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

[image]